# How to over-write the pydantic model's validation message

Tags: fastapi, pydantic

I want to change the validation message from pydantic model class, code for model class is below:

```py
class Input(BaseModel):
    ip: IPvAnyAddress

    @validator("ip", always=True)
    def not_valid_ip(cls, v):
        """To validate ip-address."""
        if str(v) == "":
            raise ValueError(f'Invalid IP-Address:: {v}')
        if not isinstance(v, IPvAnyAddress):
            raise ValueError(f'Invalid IP format:: {v}')
        return v
```

currently, it does not update the message written above. I am using fastAPI for API development.

```py
{
    "detail": [
        {
            "loc": [
                "body",
                "input",
                "ip"
            ],
            "msg": "value is not a valid IPv4 or IPv6 address",
            "type": "value_error.ipvanyaddress"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the standard validation is failing before your validators is called.

All you need to do is add `pre=True` to your validator decorator, e.g.

```
@validator("ip", always=True, pre=True)
```

Comment: Can u tell me how to override the default message when IP is not passed in request body? as of now it only displays "field required".